# jQuery edit-in-place strange behaviour

Tags: jquery

I use http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html edit-inplace plugin.

For a single editable element it works fine but I have many on my project. When I click on an element the following happens:

[image]

The actuall text disappears. Instead an `<input>` element appears. Everything I do is

```
$('th,td').editable();
```

But the table is loaded dynamically into the DOM so:

```
$('#id').load('template.html', function() {
    $('th,td').editable();
});
```

Any idea what is wrong here? Do you have an idea how to solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/2gYw2/6/ (Not working) - Add the element and click to edit it then click on td or th to see the problem.

Comment: If you make a demo http://jsfiddle.net, it would be a lot easier to help. Or link to a page where the behavior is occurring at least (non-optimal, though).

Comment: Does that mean that it works correctly if the table is not loaded dynamically?

Comment: Can you write your HTML markup of the th and td area?

Comment: I have updated my question with a link to the html

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because you haven't linked it to the plugin. My guess would be that the plugin doesn't work on `td` and `th` elements. The author recommends a newer version than what you linked to, have you tried that one?

Comment: @j08691 - I updated the fiddle with a working demo. Of course, it also appears to be working without the AJAX `$.load()` part. Hmm.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2gYw2/5/ Have a look at this, this is the problem I describe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you should call the method editable one time, no more.
I found 2 possibilities to solve this (maybe there are more solutions).

1. you create an array and store the objects which have been called with editable().
2. you add a variable to flag the call of editable in the jQuery Object

I prefer the second solution because I found it more easily to use. I just add a new function to jquery to do this.

EDIT :

I replace the variable by a class to the HTMLElement.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.refreshEditable = function(){
        $(this).each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass("not-editable")){
              $(this).addClass("not-editable");
              $(this).editable();
            }
        });
    }        
})( jQuery );


$('th,td,h2').refreshEditable();

$('#addTable').click(function(){
    $('body').append("<div><h2>Add element</h2></div>");
    $('th,td,h2').refreshEditable();
});
```

I assume it is little bad to do this but it works. The example in live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/fZq5X/4/).

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle, because I tried your code and it did not work for me

Comment: I edit the code you should copy it again because I ommit to remove something.